# asp.net web-config error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, configuration

I have still problem with asp.net project. In Visual studio when i start debug it is all good and page working but, when i try it on iis7 showse this error.

SHOW ERROR:

Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetframework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

```
Line 18:     </connectionStrings> 
Line 19:     <system.web> 
Line 20:       <compilation debug="true" targetframework="4.0" /> 
Line 21:     </system.web> Line 22:
```

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 20

It seems problem with targetFramework but i do not know if i have to configure iis server or something chane in my web-config.

thx.

Comment: The targetframework is for version 4, you probably run your web on previous version, also http://forums.asp.net/t/1491204.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.targetframework.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the .NET version on the Application pool for your website.
It must be .NET 4.0, not the .NET 2.0
[View a List of Application Pools (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771701%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: true thanks and plese how can i cange appilcation pool ? sorry i am only student an this is my first time with iis7... thx lot

Comment: Open IIS, connect to server, use Application pool tree node. Select Application pool you need and change its parameters

Comment: thx. but now show me new error: on SERVER DEFAULT WEB PAGE HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list    ................. Maybe i have to reinstal iis7...

Comment: No, you don't need to reinstall. You need to add httpmodule to the iis 7.0. Link: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Oct/10/HttpModule-and-HttpHandler-sections-in-IIS-7-webconfig-files

Comment: @Eddy `Looks like you have not installed the asp.net feature from within IIS in "Add/Remove windows component" so that all the regstration needed to run asp.net is not present in your configuration.` http://forums.iis.net/t/1149449.aspx

Comment: @Eddy this worked for that guy: (run > cmd) `run %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the application pool is set to use .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Change your application pool to be compatible with .NET 4.0.

[image: click to edit]

Open IIS then click on an application pool on the list and modify it to use .NET Framework 4.0.